# Can we clean up the [optimization] tag and its tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [tag wiki for](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/optimization/info) [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) currently reads like the following:

> Challenges tagged optimization should tend to focus on three areas:
>
> - There is exactly one observable parameter ("score") which measures the performance of attempting a puzzle in a particular approach. As
>   examples, this could be a mixed function between code size, objectives
>   reached (e.g. count from 1 to N where score depends on increasing N),
>   constraints met (e.g. penalty on repeating characters), or any
>   arbitrary but well defined set such as playing a game and measuring
>   your score, etc.
> - The performance (measured score) involves the loosely computer sciencey definition of "optimization", that is a "better" approach
>   works more efficiently or use fewer resources. (Resources is generally
>   interpreted as code size on this site, but there may be alternatives.)
> - The problem does not have an obvious solution, i.e. solutions may compete on out-performing each other rather than solving the problem
>   with the optimal methods. More specifically, in most optimization
>   problems there exists a playing field that arises from having the
>   output be a continuous function (i.e. for two similar approaches, they
>   may be measured to be distinct from each other based on details) or
>   the optimal algorithm is very hard to find / compute. (e.g. unit
>   allocation)

It describes the tag as a winning criterion tag, where the objective is to optimize some custom score of the submissions. But framing it as such has multiple problems:

- [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) already covers the definition, and *that* is the recommended winning criterion tag for that kind of challenges.
- No one these days uses [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) tag for that purpose. Instead, it is used more often where the core task itself is an optimization problem.

  - Optimization problem ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem)) is an important class of problems in computer science closely related to [decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem). Notably, many NP-complete decision problems have a twin optimization problem (e.g. TSP as an optimization problem reads as "minimize the cost of a Hamiltonian cycle", while its decision problem version reads as "does such a cycle under the given cost X exist?".) This definition suits better to the current usage of the tag.
  - Under this definition, [optimized-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimized-output) is NOT a synonym of [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization). IMHO, it should be synomymized to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) instead (assuming SE supports this).

Therefore, I propose the following:

- Change the meaning of [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) to that of an optimization problem in the CS sense.
- Re-tag all [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) / [optimized-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimized-output) challenges that follow the previous definition to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).
- Add a pointer to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) in the wiki excerpt.

OR,

- Create a new tag called [optimization-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization-problem).
- Re-tag all [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) challenges that do not follow the current definition to [optimization-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization-problem).
- Re-tag all the others to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).
- Entirely deprecate [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization).

Comment: +1, I always agree with efforts to clean up misused and poorly described tags. However, one thing of concern is that there are currently 127 challenges tagged with [optimization], meaning that we could flood the front page with any edits if we aren't careful

Answer (score 2):

## Option 2

(posting the two proposed options for voting purposes)

- Create a new tag called [optimization-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization-problem).
- Re-tag all [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) challenges that do not follow the current definition to [optimization-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization-problem).
- Re-tag all the others to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).
- Entirely deprecate [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization).

Comment: +1 I feel like [optimization] is a bit of a vague tag on a site where literally every question is about *optimising* your score. Having a slightly better named version of the tag for questions that are actually about optimisation seems like a better approach that is less likely to result in weird and inappropriate mistags later on

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1

(posting the two proposed options for voting purposes)

- Change the meaning of [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) to that of an optimization problem in the CS sense.
- Re-tag all [optimization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) / [optimized-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimized-output) challenges that follow the previous definition to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).
- Add a pointer to [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) in the wiki excerpt.